# How to split a string to an array of filtered integers?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a `DF` column which is a long strings with comma separated values, like:

- `2000,2001,2002:a,2003=b,2004,100,101,500,20`
- `101,102,20`

What I want to do is to create a new `Array<Int>` column out of it where:

1. only values starting with 2 are included
2. when a value has additional delimiter then only the first part will be returned (e.g. 2002)
3. some specific values will be excluded (let's say value = 20)
4. if the array is empty it should be filled with a default value (let's say [199])

So basically the 2 test strings should be returned as:

| stringColumn | arrayColumn |
| --- | --- |
| 2000,2001,2002:a,2003=b,2004,100,101,500,20 | [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004] |
| 101,102,20 | [199] |

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the problem into subproblems:
a) split string to substrings
b) try to find the number in every substring
c) if number is in substring then check if it meets the conditions

e.g.:

```py
import re

pattern = r'2[0-9]*'
excluded = (20, )

long_str = "2000,2001,2002:a,2003=b,2004,100,101,500,20"


def foo(l_str: str, pattern=pattern, excluded=excluded):
    result = []
    for num in l_str.split(','):
        search_res = re.search(pattern, num)
        if search_res and\
                (x := int(search_res.group())) not in excluded:
            result.append(x)
    return result
    
foo(long_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a custom user defined function to extract and filter values. Here is an approach:

```
import re

@F.udf(returnType='array<int>')
def find_all(s):
    exclude = ['20']
    items = re.findall(r'\b(2\d+)\b', s)
    return [int(x) for x in items if x not in exclude] or [199]


df = df.withColumn('arrayColumn', find_all('stringColumn'))
```

Result

```
df.show()

+--------------------+--------------------+
|        stringColumn|         arrayColumn|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|2000,2001,2002:a,...|[2000, 2001, 2002...|
|          101,102,20|               [199]|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```